# IF NOT EXISTS vs @@ROWCOUNT - Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Which one should I use for the best performance?

This one:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (...where Id = 'x')
    INSERT...'x'
ELSE 
    UPDATE...WHERE Id = 'x'
```

Or this one:

```
UPDATE...WHERE Id = 'x'
if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT...'x'
```

Comment: I would use MERGE instead.

Comment: I can't use merge. It is not supported by sql2005.

Comment: Well that wasn't in the question. :) Have you tried them to see which is better? I always used the second version back in the day for this type of "upsert"

Comment: I'm using it in large queries. I have like over 1 million records. I tried with the `Display Estimated Execution Plan` in `SQL Management`, but the result is not good I have execution plans with over 400%...

Comment: I guess the second one is better if the record typically exists, the first one might be better otherwise. In both cases you need to look at transaction level (serialisation) and retry.

Comment: If most of the records already exist, the 2nd form is faster in my experience. However, if you updating / inserting  a number of rows, you are still better of by joining to the target table and performing 2 set based inserts. I.e., update where exists in target table followed by insert where not exists.

Comment: @eckes Query Cost: 400%

Comment: Here is a analysis which tells us the check is very efficient: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling

Comment: Estimated plans and the percentages listed are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think performance is going to matter much between the two versions you proposed.

To me, the real question is how to deal with database activity between your statements.  What happens if someone tries to INSERT a row immediately after the NOT EXISTS check in your first example or the UPDATE in your second example?  Is this happening inside a transaction?  If so, what is your isolation level?

`MERGE` would be better, but you said that's not an option because you need to support SQL Server 2005.

What we've done for SQL Server 2005 is to perform both the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE`.  Start with the `UPDATE`, so you don't `UPDATE` a row you just created with an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE Persons
SET PersonName = 'Ted'
WHERE PersonID = 6

;WITH Data(Id, Name)
AS (SELECT 6, 'Ted')
INSERT MyTable (PersonId, PersonName)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Data
    LEFT JOIN Persons ON PersonId = Id
WHERE PersonId IS NULL -- the person does not already exist
```

This routine makes more sense for larger bulk operations where some of the data might already exist, but it can be used for a single update.

Another consideration: do you need to track if someone else changed the row?  If so, I'd recommend adding a `timestamp`(`rowversion` in newer version) column and failing the `UPDATE` if the timestamp is different.

For example, say Alice is editing the person ID 6 named 'Bill'.  After she opens Bill's row, Charlie opens Bill's row, enters some information, and saves the changes.  When Alice saves her changes, she will overwrite Charlie's changes.

Comment: transactions are not important in my case. I'm trying to execute your example on my table, but I don't get it. For example: I have a table `Persons` with a column `PersonID`. I dont get the `Data(Id, ...)`. Can you please, provide me a full example? Like: `Update Persons set PersonID = 7 where PersonID = 6....`

Comment: If an ID is unique, changing it might not make sense (depends on your data).  I updated the example to include a more specific query.

Answer (score 2):

Just use SET STATISTICS TIME ON/OFF to actually measure it if you're not sure.  For example:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
-- put your SQL to test here
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

Now select the block and execute it (you have to actually execute it, so use a test environment and a copy of the database).  You'll get explicit information on exactly what happened, and should be able to use that to determine which is faster.

And as others have indicated, the result may vary depending on whether in actual usage, you do more updates, or more inserts.

Comment: I would also recommend using SET STATISTICS IO ON as that will give you the number of scans, logical reads, etc. which can give you additional insight than just the time it takes to execute.  I typically use both STATISTICS IO and TIME when doing investigations like this.

Comment: You've put your actual SQL to test in between the ON and OFF lines?  And you're running the tests against a table with actual data in it?  If that's the case, and they both give you 0ms, then I'd wager you can use whichever one you like better personally, as the performance wouldn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: I have looked at this comparison before and the difference is negligible in most cases.  As mentioned before the UPDATE ; IF @@ROWCOUNT approach will be slightly faster if the row is actually there, but only in that case